# Why is $\pm\ln(a+\sqrt b)=\ln(a\pm\sqrt b)$, given that $a\pm\sqrt b>0$?

Tags: complex-analysis, logarithms

> Why is $\pm\ln(a+\sqrt b)=\ln(a\pm\sqrt b)$, given that $a\pm\sqrt b>0$)?

I remember being taught this proof by my teacher, but I forgot. I think it was obtained from the derivation of $\ln(-x)$.
Any help is appreciated.

**Edit:** Is this true for solutions of a quadratic equation where both roots are greater than zero?

Thanks

Comment: You would need $a^2-b=1$ for that to be correct.

Answer (score 1):

This is not true in general. Instead, from $(a-\sqrt b)(a+\sqrt b)=a^2-b$, we conclude 
$$\ln(a-\sqrt b)=\ln(a^2-b)-\ln(a+\sqrt b)$$
(which matches your equation only if $a^2=b+1$)

Comment: From solutions of a quadratic equation, the result holds, could you try to prove this?

Comment: Since you don't seem to get it: the "result" is false. Just put in $a=2$ and $b=1$. Then $\ln(a-\sqrt b) = \ln 1 = 0$ but $-\ln(a+\sqrt b) = -\ln 3$, which is negative.